# regular unipotent elements

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

Let $G$ be a finite simple group of Lie type over a finite field of characteristic $p\neq 2$ and $q$ elements. We know that if $p$ is not bad for $G$ then $G$ contains $q^l$ regular unipotent elements where $l$ is the semisimple rank of $G$ and all of them are conjugate in $G$ (See p.130 and p.131 of [Carter's book](http://books.google.com/books/about/Finite_groups_of_Lie_type.html?id=LvvuAAAAMAAJ)). So $|C_G(u)|=q^l$ where $u$ is a regular unipotent element.

Now let $u_0$ be a $p$-element which its centralizer is a $p$-group. Is it true that $u_0$ is a regular unipotent element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Distinguished unipotent elements:

I think the answer is close to no: on page 173 Carter describes the $p$-elements so that $C_G(u)_o$ is a $p$-group, the so-called **distinguished** unipotent elements. Most simple algebraic groups contain more than one conjugacy class of distinguished unipotent elements as on page 174-177.

I checked the results in [magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/), but things did not work out quite as desired. I haven't found any “really distinguished” classes, where the entire centralizer (not just its connected component) is a $p$-group. [ I've only checked a few cases, Cn and G2; An doesn't work. ]

#### Simple versus adjoint:

Unfortunately, you have a slight misinterpretation of Carter's statements. In groups like $G=\operatorname{PGL}$, there will be a single conjugacy class of regular unipotent elements, and its centralizer will be a $p$-group. The good news is that the unipotent elements is necessarily contained within the simple group $O^{p'}(G)$ (like $\operatorname{PSL}$). The bad news is that since the centralizer is also a $p$-group, the centralizer is also contained within $O^{p'}(G)$, and so necessarily will split into $[G:O^{p'}(G)]$ classes (such as $\gcd(n,q-1)$ for our running example).

As another example, $\operatorname{PSp}(2n,p^f)$ has two conjugacy classes of elements whose centralizers are of order $p^{2f}=q^2$. I believe it has no other conjugacy classes whose centralizers are $p$-groups (it does not for small $n,p,f$).

Comment: I understood from your answer, that it is possible to have two conjugacy classes with a $p$-group as its centralizer. However I couldn't find any example. This means that the answer is no. But I didn't understand what is my mistake in using the Proposition 5.1.9. of carter's book? Is the number of regular unipotent elements equal to $q^l$?

Comment: Prop 5.1.9 does not apply to (most) simple groups of Lie type. It applies to almost-simple groups-of-Lie-type of-adjoint-type.  For example, PSL(3,7) has 3 conjugacy classes of elements whose centralizer is a $p$-group, but those 3 conjugacy classes are all regular elements. 7 is not a bad prime for PSL3. Prop 5.1.9 does not apply to PSL. Prop 5.1.9 applies to PGL.

Comment: (p=7 is fixed in my last comment; PSL(3,7) also has some elements whose centralizers are 2-groups and 19-groups, but they aren't relevant to your question or my answer).

Comment: Ok! But is it true that if $G$ has two conjugacy classes of elements whose centralizer is a $p$-group, then these centralizers have the same length? (Actually I couldn't find any counter example for this!)If yes, why?

Comment: The “distinguished” stuff makes me think the answer should be no, but I could not find any counterexample using it. (So, “I don't know” is my answer. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I try to find it!

Comment: Another question, is it possible that $C_G(x)$ be a $p$-group where $x$ is a central element of a sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$?

Comment: It should be very uncommon. If the Sylow $p$-subgroup is cyclic (so very low rank), it probably isn't hard. PSL(2,q) should work for odd q.